# how to define a C++ method outside the declaration for a variadic templated class specialized to no parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have a variadic templated class that I want to specialize to take no parameters and then I want to define methods outside the class declaration.

But the following gives

```
error: template-id ‘foobar<>’ for ‘foobar<>::foobar()’ does not 
match any template declaration
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
template <typename ...> class foobar;

template <>
class foobar <> 
{
    foobar();
};

//does not work!?
template <>
foobar<>::foobar() {};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor isn't a template, since it's a non-template member of a full specialisation, so it doesn't need `template` in its declaration:

```
// does work
foobar<>::foobar() {}
```